# Compiler Error in C -- Expected ')' before '!' token.

Tags: c, compiler-errors, while-loop, palindrome

I'm coding a basic program to check if a string is a palindrome or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>             //Has some very useful functions for strings. 
#include <ctype.h>              //Can sort between alphanumeric, punctuation, etc.

int main(void)
{

char a[100];
char b[100];                            //Two strings, each with 100 characters. 

int firstchar;
int midchar;
int lastchar;

int length = 0;
int counter = 0;

printf(" Enter a phrase or word for palindrome checking: \n \n ");

    while ((a[length] == getchar())  !10 )      //Scanning for input ends if the user presses enter. 
    {
        if ((a[length -1]), isalpha)                // If a character isalpha, keep it. 
        {
            b[counter] = a[length-1];
            counter++;
        }

    length--;           //Decrement. 
    }

makelower(b, counter);                      //Calls the function that changes uppercase to lowercase. 


for( firstchar = 0; firstchar < midchar; firstchar++ )  //Compares the first and last characters. 
    {
    if ( a[firstchar] != a[lastchar] )
        {
            printf(", is not a palindrome. \n \n");
            break;
        }
    lastchar--;
    }   

if( firstchar == midchar ) 
    {
        printf(", is a palindrome. \n \n");
    }


return 0;
}


//Declaring additional function "makelower" to change everything remaining to lowercase chars. 


int makelower (char c[100], int minicount)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (count <= minicount)
    {
        c[count] = tolower(c[count]);
    }
return 0;
}
```

And I'm getting the following compiler error on the line with the first while loop, immediately after the printf statement:

```
p5.c: In function 'main':
p5.c:30: error: expected ')' before '!' token
```

I've looked up and down, but I haven't found any out-of-place or nonpartnered parenthesis. The only thing I can think of is that I'm missing a comma or some kind of punctuation, but I've tried placing a comma in a few places to no avail.

Sorry if this is too specific. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `(a[length] == getchar())  !10 ` <-- what is that supposed to do? Reducing it (to show why it doesn't make sense and is an *invalid* syntax construct) yields `(expr) !10`. Remember that `!` is a unary operator; it cannot appear in an infix location. Then, compare with `(expr) != 0` - bad typing, perhaps?

Comment: did u mean " != 10 " ? (not equal to 10)

Comment: If you need two conditions, you need to connect them by && (and) or || (or).

Comment: lenght=0, so how a[lenght-1] ?!

Comment: It was meant to be !=10, which was meant to correspond to 'Enter'. But I believe Enter/Return is actually 13 for ANSI. Thank you for your input everyone.

Comment: Also `if ((a[length -1]), isalpha)` is _terribly_ wrong.

Answer (score 3):

```
while ((a[length] == getchar())  !10 )
```

What it looks like you're trying for is assigning to `a[length]` the result of `getchar()` and verifying that that is not equal to `10`.  Which is spelled like so:

```
while ((a[length] = getchar()) != 10)
```

`=` is assignment, `==` is the test.

Further, your counters are confused.  `length` is initialized to `0` and is only decremented, which will lead to falling off the front of the array after the first decrement.  This doesn't get a chance to happen, because you attempt to access `a[length-1]`, which will also fail.  This looks like a [off-by-one error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error), also known as a [fencepost error](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/F/fencepost-error.html), in accessing the character you just read from getchar().

Also, since nothing is checking that the length of recorded input doesn't exceed the length of your buffer `a[100]`, you could fall off the end there as well.

The counters for your palindrome check function are also off.  `midchar` and `lastchar` are never initialized, `midchar` is never set, and `lastchar` is decremented without ever having a value set.  You would probably be better off testing `a[firstchar] == a[(counter-1)-firstchar]`.

Comment: Also, getchar() returns an int, and you're putting that into a character array. At the end of the file, this will put character 255 into the string and fall into an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not terribly familiar with the return values of getchar().